# Проблема в fedora 24 при попытке запустить какую-либо команду связанную с dnf

Tags: fedora

При попытке запустить с консоли , к примеру, `sudo dnf update`, получаю в результате

> Failed to set locale, defaulting to C

и множество строк непонятного когда. Как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте выполнить `export LC_ALL="C"` в консоли. Это решит вашу проблему, но только для текущей сессии.

Чтобы решить эту проблему навсегда, вы можете открыть файл `/etc/profile` и в самом верху добавить `export LC_ALL="C"`